# How to fix 'variable is not defined' in node terminal and why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I defined a variable and assigned it a function which had syntax error. It throws error. Now, I am unable to use that variable for anything, it always say 'Thrown:
ReferenceError: variable is not defined'

```
> let bg = 'asasas-123d'
undefined
> let fd = bg.substring(indexOf('-')+1)
Thrown:
ReferenceError: indexOf is not defined
> let fd = bg.substring(bg.indexOf('-')+1)
Thrown:
SyntaxError: Identifier 'fd' has already been declared
>  fd = bg.substring(bg.indexOf('-')+1)
Thrown:
ReferenceError: fd is not defined
> let  fd = bg.substring(bg.indexOf('-')+1)
Thrown:
SyntaxError: Identifier 'fd' has already been declared
> fd = bg.substring(bg.indexOf('-')+1)
Thrown:
ReferenceError: fd is not defined
> fd
Thrown:
ReferenceError: fd is not defined
> console.log(fd);
Thrown:
ReferenceError: fd is not defined
```

Comment: Note that `indexOf` is a property of iterable objects, not a variable.

Comment: The console execution context is weird. *When there's assignment, the right-hand side is parsed first; if the right-hand side throws an error, it never gets to the left-hand side, and the variable declared with let never gets properly initialized; it'll stay in the demilitarized zone / temporal dead zone forever*. You probably meant to use something like `bg.substring(bg.indexOf`, because `indexOf` is not a standalone function (you might consider using a regular expression instead, too)

Comment: Hi Dragon! Welcome to the boards. It looks like you have a typo which may be the cause of this entire error. let fd = bg.substring(indexOf('-')+1)   I believe you mean bg.indexOf

Comment: yes, i meant that only. I made a typo. I am actually confused about why is it not allowing me to access that variable again?
If I use 'let fd = something' it says it has been already declared.
If I use 'fd = something' it says it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your terminal and run this:

```
> let bg = 'asasas-123d'
> let fd = bg.substring(bg.indexOf("-") + 1))
```

Comment: My question is How can a variable be declared but not defined.
I know that was a typo and I corrected in later steps, but it is not allowing me to do so.